# Fragment and older version of android, why error inflating fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know there are too many questions about that, but no one of them resolve my problems.

So... my codes:

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);
    }

}
```

ArticleFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

news_articles.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tryied with Fragment and fragment. Didn't work.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.fragmenttestina"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.fragmenttestina.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I got:

ClassNotFoundException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Fragment

I got android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder and its in build path....

SOLVED:

Sorry, I just lost one day cause of my lack of attention. I haven't set the name of fragment. I think that just this was the problem. Sorry for your time and thanks anyway.

Comment: In your description, you have written the same code for "ArticleFragment" class.

Comment: I have fixed this. Missclick, sorry.

Comment: @Curlyman Please post a complete answer if you figured it out so that others can benefit.

Comment: Thanks for posting such a complete resolution of your error Curly, really helped solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your xml-

```
<android.support.v4.app.Fragment />
```